# Preventing debugging session from pausing after each inferior exits

Tags: debugging, gdb, multiple-processes

I'm debugging a tree of processes using [`gdb`'s very handy multiple-inferior support](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html):

```
(gdb) set detach-on-fork off
(gdb) set schedule-multiple on
(gdb) set follow-fork-mode parent
(gdb) break PostgresMain
(gdb) break PostmasterMain
```

and now need to let things run until I hit one of the future breakpoints in some yet to be spawned inferior.

However, `gdb` seems to be "helpfully" pausing whenever an inferior exits normally, or at least blocking cleanup of the inferior so that its parent's `wait()` can return:

```
(gdb) c
[New process 16505]
process 16505 is executing new program: /home/craig/pg/bdr/bin/pg_config
Reading symbols from /home/craig/pg/bdr/bin/pg_config...done.
[Inferior 2 (process 16505) exited normally]
(gdb) info inferior
  Num  Description       Executable        
* 2    <null>            /home/craig/pg/bdr/bin/pg_config 
  1    process 16501     /usr/bin/make     
(gdb) inferior 1
[Switching to inferior 1 [process 16501] (/usr/bin/make)]
[Switching to thread 1 (process 16501)] 
#0  0x0000003bc68bc502 in __libc_wait (stat_loc=0x7fffffffbc78) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wait.c:30
30          return INLINE_SYSCALL (wait4, 4, WAIT_ANY, stat_loc, 0,
(gdb)
```

so I have to endlessly:

```
(gdb) inferior 1
(gdb) c
```

to carry on. About 70 times, before I hit the desired breakpoint in a child of a child of a child.

I *think* what's happening is that `gdb` treats process exit as a stop event, and since `non-stop` is set to `off` (the default) it stops all threads in all inferiors when one thread stops. However, this inferior has terminated, it isn't a normal stop event, so you can't just `cont` it, you have to switch to another process first.

Is there some way to stop gdb pausing at each inferior exit? I would've expected `follow-fork-mode parent` with `schedule-multiple on` to do the trick, but `gdb` seems to still want to stop when an inferior exits.

I guess I'm looking for something like a "skip proc-exit", or a virtual signal I can change the handler policy on so it doesn't stop.

---

`set non-stop on` seems like it should be the right answer, but I suspect it's broken for multiple inferiors.

If I use `non-stop on`, then after the first exit trap, `gdb`'s internal state indicates that inferior 1 is running:

```
(gdb) info inferior
  Num  Description       Executable        
* 1    process 20540     /usr/bin/make     
(gdb) info thread
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    process 20540 "make" (running)
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Cannot execute this command while the selected thread is running.
```

but the kernel sees it as blocked on `ptrace_stop`:

```
$ ps -o "cmd,wchan" -p 20540
CMD                         WCHAN
/usr/bin/make check         ptrace_stop
```

... and it makes no progress until `gdb` is detached, or it's killed. Signals to the process are ignored, and `interrupt` in `gdb` has no effect.

---

I'm using `GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.7.1-18.fc20` on x86_64.

Comment: What if define `hook-stop` (`defining (‘hook-stop’) makes the associated commands execute every time execution stops in your program`)? Might it be useful in your situation? Can you check? This is link: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html

Comment: @skwllsp The trouble with using a stop-hook handler is that it'll also merrily switch inferiors and continue when a breakpoint is hit. There doesn't seem to be a way to hook-stop only for the "inferior exited" case, without also affecting the other cases. Like, say, single-stepping.

Comment: @skwllsp I thought I'd solved it with a Python extension (per deleted answer), but no, that causes issues with stepping too. An "inferior [n] nostop" or similar is needed.

Comment: ... and the `non-stop on` behaviour looks increasingly like a bug, where the parent gets stopped (wchan=ptrace_stop) but gdb thinks it's running, so it won't `cont` it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After [stumbling on a post that references it in passing](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=734) I found that the missing magic is `set target-async on` alongside `set non-stop on`.

non-stop mode, as expected, means gdb won't stop everything whenever an inferior exits. `target-async` is required to make it actually work correctly on gdb 7.7; it's the default on 7.8.

So the full incantation is:

```
set detach-on-fork off
set schedule-multiple on
set follow-fork-mode parent
set non-stop on
set target-async on
```

For 7.8, remove `target-async on` and, to reduce noise, add `set print symbol-loading off`.

Answer (score 2):

The following Python extension to gdb will switch back to the first inferior and resume execution after each stop.

It feels like a total hack, but it works. When a process exits it sets a flag indicating that it stopped on an exit, then switches to the original process. `gdb` will then stop execution, delivering a stop event. We check to see if the stop was caused by our stop event and if so, we immediately continue.

The code also sets up the breakpoints I'm using and the multi-process settings, so I can just `source thescript.py` and `run` .

```python
my_stop_request = False

gdb.execute("set python print-stack full")
gdb.execute("set detach-on-fork off")
gdb.execute("set schedule-multiple on")
gdb.execute("set follow-fork-mode parent")

gdb.execute("set breakpoint pending on")
gdb.execute("break PostgresMain")
gdb.execute("break PostmasterMain")
gdb.execute("set breakpoint pending off")

def do_continue():
    gdb.execute("continue")

def exit_handler(event):
    global my_stop_request
    has_threads = [ inferior.num for inferior in gdb.inferiors() if inferior.threads() ]
    if has_threads:
        has_threads.sort()
        gdb.execute("inferior %d" % has_threads[0])
        my_stop_request = True

gdb.events.exited.connect(exit_handler)

def stop_handler(event):
    global my_stop_request
    if isinstance(event, gdb.SignalEvent):
        pass
    elif isinstance(event, gdb.BreakpointEvent):
        pass
    elif my_stop_request:
        my_stop_request = False
        gdb.post_event(do_continue)

gdb.events.stop.connect(stop_handler)
```

There must be an easier way than this. It's ugly.