# GDB: debugging 2 process simultaneously

Tags: c++, c, debugging, parallel-processing, gdb

Let say I want to debug **2 instances** of my program "Program.exe", each one with a different argument ("one" and "two"). Also I need to run both process at the same time (or at least within 1 second).

I've read that GDB's inferiors lets you run and debug multiple programs in a single session. And this is my try:

```
file Program.exe
set args one

add-inferior
inferior 2
file Program.exe
set args two

run
```

But not success. Only one inferior is running

Any idea?
I'm considering these two options:

- Creating a new program that forks the process, then GDB can handle both processes through "set detach-on-fork off" but this approach seems to me a bit ugly...
- Launching two processes normally and then attach them by PID in GDB. But my environment is Windows and I don't know how to do that nor how to find PID by command line argument.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only have one `run` command, so it's not surprising that only one inferior runs. What happens if you `run` the first inferior, before switching to the second one?

Comment: But I wan to rum both simultaneously. Its a requirement

Comment: You could stry `set schedule-multiple on`, with this setting any execution command `run`, `continue`, etc will run all threads in all inferiors: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/All_002dStop-Mode.html#index-set-schedule_002dmultiple

Comment: Thanks @Andrew but `set schedule-multiple on` only applies to the commands `continue`, `next` or `step`. I tried your solution but only the last inferior runs

Comment: Things never ever happen simultaneously in this world, only within a specified time interval from each other.

Comment: I'm totally disagree with your statement but I've edit my question to be more flexible

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt almost works, you just need `starti` in addition. After you have started every process, a single `continue` can be used to launch all processes.

```
$ gdb
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb) set schedule-multiple on
```

Remember to set the above, otherwise the second `starti` will hang.

Start the first inferior.

```
(gdb) file bash
Reading symbols from bash...
(No debugging symbols found in bash)
(gdb) set args -c "echo one; sleep 1; echo three"
(gdb) starti
Starting program: /usr/bin/bash -c "echo one; sleep 1; echo three"

Program stopped.
0x00007ffff7fe52a0 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Add and start the second inferior.

```
(gdb) add-inferior
[New inferior 2]
Added inferior 2 on connection 1 (native)
(gdb) inferior 2
[Switching to inferior 2 [<null>] (<noexec>)]
(gdb) file bash
Reading symbols from bash...
(No debugging symbols found in bash)
(gdb) set args -c "sleep 0.5; echo two; sleep 1; echo four"
(gdb) starti
Starting program: /usr/bin/bash -c "sleep 0.5; echo two; sleep 1; echo four"

Thread 2.1 "bash" stopped.
0x00007ffff7fe52a0 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Continue both inferiors.

```
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
one
[Detaching after fork from child process 364313]
[Detaching after fork from child process 364314]
two
[Detaching after fork from child process 364315]
three
[Inferior 1 (process 364277) exited normally]
```

At this point, inferior 1 stops, and gdb stops everything. If you don't like this behavior, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27163134/5267751 .

We continue running the second inferior to completion.

```
(gdb) info inferior
  Num  Description       Connection           Executable        
* 1    <null>                                 /usr/bin/bash     
  2    process 364312    1 (native)           /usr/bin/bash     
(gdb) inferior 2
[Switching to inferior 2 [process 364312] (/usr/bin/bash)]
[Switching to thread 2.1 (Thread 0x7ffff7cda740 (LWP 364312))]
#0  0x00007ffff7e4e187 in wait4 () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
four
[Inferior 2 (process 364312) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Comment: Nitpick: as mentioned in a comment, (probably by theory of relativity?) we cannot define simultaneity of two events happening at different points in space. I assume what OP really want is to allow **interleaving of execution**.